# How to get a variable from a script to other script in corona sdk (Lua)

Tags: variables, lua, coronasdk

I want to get a variable i made from a script like `main.lua` and get it to `menu.lua` .

Comment: How are those two scripts related? Does `main` import `menu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I will give you two.

### Global Variables

Probably the easiest way, but also can get messy really fast.

your-project/main.lua

```
--
-- main.lua
--
myVariableFromMain1 = "hello world"
myVariableFromMain2 = "another sample variable"
composer.gotoScene( "menu" )
```

your-project/menu.lua

```
--
-- menu.lua
--
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    print(myVariableFromMain1) -- prints "hello world!"
    print(myVariableFromMain2) -- prints "another sample variable"
end
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
return scene
```

### Passing a parameter in `composer.gotoScene( ... )`

This is the way Corona recommends. See `Scene Options` in https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/gotoScene.html

your-project/main.lua

```
--
-- main.lua
--
composer.gotoScene( "menu", { params = {
    myVariableFromMain1 = "hello world!",
    myVariableFromMain2 = "another sample variable"
}} )
```

your-project/menu.lua

```
--
-- menu.lua
--
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    print(myVariableFromMain) -- prints "hello world!"
end
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
return scene
```

If you wish to learn about another way to have `menu.lua` and `main.lua` share information, just ask me in the comments. I'm happy to add to this post.